# VSCode Jest Failing with SystaxError: Unexpected token =

Tags: visual-studio-code, jestjs

The VScode Jest extension fails to run the the tests with output:

```
module.exports = (filename, opts = {}) => {
                                 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)

Starting Jest in Watch mode failed too many times and has been stopped.
 see troubleshooting: https://github.com/jest-community/vscode-jest/blob/master/README.md#troubleshooting
```

I'm using webpack as described here: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/webpack

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the system's node version.

vscode-jest runs on the system node, ignoring NVM versions.

To fix this make sure your system's node version is set to the specific node version your project is running, in my case it needs v8.16.0.

In order to upgrade your system's node (in case you are using Ubuntu) follow the next instructions:
https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md#deb